# Update Value of Session of only a single key in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have an input like below.

```
array:4 [  
  "_token" => "evktHCfCNZVQMNYXzntfHZkdNLZFqvOoYgU3yPKy"
  "name" => "Name"
  "orderId" => "5cb5943a6733a1555403834"
  "amount" => null
]
```

which I stored to a session like this:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{    
    request()->session()->put('bookingInfo', $request->input());

    return redirect()->route('book.checkout');
}
```

Now I want to change the `amount` value in the session. How I am going to achieve that?

Comment: Please show some code.

Comment: What is stopping you?

Comment: @Zendy Help here

Comment: Let me confirm this... Are you trying to change the `amount` before or after it has been put inside session?

Comment: @Zendy After it has been put inside session. The value is null when it is put inside the session . now i want to update the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update the value, you need to retrieve the values from session and update it again.

To do that, you need to do

```
$booking_info = $request->session()->get('bookingInfo');
```

Then you will got an array back. Update it like a normal array

```
$booking_info["amount"] = 10; // anything you wanted
```

If you need to put it back into session again you can do this

```
$request->session()->put('bookingInfo', $booking_info);
```

**EDIT**

If you want the ability to update partially, you would need to store it separately like this.

```
$input = $request->all();
$request->session()->put('bookingInfo.name', $input['name']);
$request->session()->put('bookingInfo.orderId', $input['orderId']);
$request->session()->put('bookingInfo.amount', $input['amount']);
```

Comment: btw, it means we have to update the whole session; Cant update the only value?
The Above Answer Works. Thanks

Comment: Nice! If this answer solved your problem, you could mark it as accepted answer by clicking the checkmark left side of this answer. About your other question, I edited the answer to cover that. @TeachMe

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 5+
// Via a request instance...

```
$request->session()->put('amount', 'value');
```

// Via the global helper...

```
session(['amount' => 'value']);
```

// For retrieve

```
session('amount');
```